# SQL Server - Return TOP X items based on aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have a SQL query that I have been running, but I'm getting way too much data than what I need.

For context, we carry about 3000 items, across 30 product categories, and 50 sub-categories (parent-child relationship). We sell them in thousands of stores, and our database captures the weekly sales per store per product.  We store for multiple years worth of data.

Currently my query returns all records, while I would like to limit it to the top10 selling items, based on the sum of their unit sales for the latest 52 weeks (my where clause specifies the 52 weeks, but I need the weekly details in my pull).

```
SELECT
store.store_id,
store.sales_rep,
store.sales_rep_manager,
prod.category,
prod.sub_category,
prod.item,
sales.week_id,
sum(sales.units) as "UNITS SOLD",
sum(sale.dollars) as "DOLLARS SOLD"
...
GROUP BY
store.store_id,
store.sales_rep,
store.sales_rep_manager,
prod.category,
prod.sub_category,
prod.item,
sales.week_id,
ORDER BY
7 desc
```

I think I should be using a TOP statement, but all I've succeeded in doing was limit the entire pull to top 10 records overall.

What I would like to see is the top 10 items based on unit velocity for the date range selected, but for each store & sub-category

Store1
Category1
Sub-Category1
TOP SELLING Item #1
TOP SELLING Item #2
TOP SELLING Item #3
...
TOP SELLING Item #10

Right now I've connected my query in Excel, and I ask my pivot table to filter only top10 items.

My issue with this solution is I'm bringing a TON more data than what I need, making the file irresponsive, too big, and also takes a lot of time to complete Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the results to the *total* sales in the result set pretty easily:

```
with q as (<your query here>)
select q.*
from (select q.*, dense_rank() over (order by TotalUs) as rnk
      from (select q.*,
                  sum("Units Sold") over (partition by prod.item) as TotalUS
            from q
           ) q
      ) q
where rnk <= 10;
```

Getting it for the last year is a little trickier:

```
with q as (<your query here>)
select q.*
from (select q.*, dense_rank() over (order by TotalUs) as rnk
      from (select q.*,
                  sum(last_52weeks) over (partition by prod.item) as TotalUS
            from (select q.*,
                         (case when dense_rank() over (partition by item_id order by week_id desc) <= 52
                               then "Units Sold" else 0
                          end) as last_52weeks
                  from q
                 ) q
           ) q
      ) q
where rnk <= 10;
```

Comment: This is probably right but I need to digest it before I can try to apply it on my query.  I think I may have chewed on a piece bigger than what I can handle.

Comment: So when you do 'WITH q AS (query), you are creating result set with the query I proposed above.

Comment: Then the syntax kills me.  If I understand correctly I need to pretty much read it backwards.  You partition the results and sum the units in each item (I think this should be sub_category) and name that sum TotalUS.    You then rank these results  (I think rank is better for me here than dense_rank).    Then you apply the where statement on that new rank column.  Did I get that right @Gordon Linoff ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to approach these types of problems using cascading CTEs. I've noticed that this format can solve fairly complex problems, while still being somewhat more readable. The data kind of flows from one CTE to the next, then comes out with the SELECT statement at the end.

Here's an example that I put together for this case. The data itself is somewhat questionable, as `store_id` 5 is really the only one with more than 10 items sold, but it's really just a demonstration so hopefully you can still get the big picture. Obviously your data structure is quite different, but you should be able to make adjustments as needed to make it work with your real setup:

```
--===================================================================
-- Create and populate a table for demonstration purposes only:
--===================================================================

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Sales') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Sales;
CREATE TABLE #Sales (
    item_id INT,
    category VARCHAR(10),
    sub_category VARCHAR(10),
    store_id INT,
    week_id INT,
    units INT,
    dollars MONEY
);

INSERT INTO #Sales
VALUES  (1, 'A', 'A1', 1, 1, 10, 50),
        (1, 'A', 'A1', 2, 1, 10, 50),
        (1, 'A', 'A1', 3, 1, 10, 50),
        (1, 'A', 'A1', 4, 1, 10, 50),
        (1, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 20, 50),
        (2, 'B', 'B1', 1, 1, 20, 50),
        (2, 'B', 'B1', 2, 1, 20, 50),
        (2, 'B', 'B1', 3, 1, 20, 50),
        (2, 'B', 'B1', 4, 1, 20, 50),
        (2, 'B', 'B1', 5, 1, 20, 50),
        (3, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 40, 50),
        (4, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 10, 50),
        (5, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 5, 50),
        (6, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 100, 50),
        (7, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 95, 50),
        (8, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 35, 50),
        (9, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 15, 50),
        (10, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 11, 50),
        (11, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 12, 50),
        (12, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 49, 50),
        (12, 'A', 'A1', 5, 1, 150, 50);


--===================================================================
-- The actual query starts here:
-- (note that the following is a single statement)
--===================================================================

WITH AggregatedSales AS (
    -- This CTE will give you the totals for each store, for each item and category / sub-category:
    SELECT
        s.store_id,
        s.category,
        s.sub_category,
        s.item_id,
        --s.week_id, -- If you want to see the combined data for the entire date range, don't include week here
        SUM(s.units) [total_units_sold],
        SUM(s.dollars) [total_dollars_sold]
    FROM #Sales s
    WHERE s.week_id BETWEEN 1 AND 52 -- Adjust these to match your actual range
    GROUP BY
        s.store_id,
        s.category,
        s.sub_category,
        s.item_id
        --s.week_id
),
RankedSales AS (
    -- This will assign a ranking to each of the records from the previous CTE.
    -- The ranking is reset for each store, and ranks higher number of units sold toward the top.
    SELECT
        a.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY a.store_id
            ORDER BY a.total_units_sold DESC
        ) [ranking]
    FROM AggregatedSales a
)
-- Now we just select all of the "TOP 10" ranked items here:
-- (the WHERE clause is doing all the work in this case, so we don't need an actual TOP)
SELECT
    rs.*
FROM RankedSales rs
WHERE rs.ranking <= 10
ORDER BY
    rs.store_id,
    rs.ranking;
```